# Amazon AWS DynamoDB Desktop Client - Does one exist?

Tags: amazon-web-services, desktop-application, amazon-dynamodb

Been looking around on the web for one of these, but I'm only finding node.js/ruby hosted implementations.

I'm keen to have a DynamoDB app, something like that of the navicat ilk that comes with an msi installer to get running quickly.

Maybe there's a valid reason as to why one of these doesn't exist yet?

Comment: Could you please comment on the hosted implementations you are referring to? This would ease comparing the desired feature set, thanks.

Comment: Helping for the newcomers,
1. Amazon just released workbench here https://aws.amazon.com/tr/about-aws/whats-new/2019/09/introducing-nosql-workbench-for-amazon-dynamodb-now-in-preview/

There is also a tool called &#39;dynobase&#39; , it has a free version. https://dynobase.dev/

If you want new features you can ask the developer, he is on reddit.
https://www.reddit.com/r/aws/comments/dg0o9e/i_made_alternative_ui_for_dynamodb_console_check/?utm_medium=android_app&amp;amp;amp;utm_source=share

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/workbench.settingup.html

Comment: The official one from amazon is NoSQL Workbench: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/workbench.settingup.html

Comment: Disclaimer: I'm creator of this software. Try https://dynobase.dev

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I'm not aware of a dedicated desktop application for using [Amazon DynamoDB](http://aws.amazon.com/dynamodb/) from Windows yet.

However, the AWS Toolkits for [Eclipse](http://aws.amazon.com/eclipse/) and [Visual Studio](http://aws.amazon.com/visualstudio/) both allow you to create tables, insert and edit data, initiate table scans, and more, straight from your local development environment (see the introductory post [AWS Toolkits for Eclipse and Visual Studio Now Support DynamoDB](http://aws.typepad.com/aws/2012/01/aws-toolkits-for-eclipse-and-visual-studio-now-support-dynamodb.html)).

So depending on your use case this might be all you need (or even better, if this is targeting a development scenario).

---

#### Update

The AWS team has just announced the option to [Explore Your DynamoDB Tables Using the AWS Management Console](http://aws.typepad.com/aws/2012/05/explore-your-dynamodb-tables-using-the-aws-management-console.html) as well:

> You can now view and modify the contents of your DynamoDB tables from
>   within the AWS Management Console. With the addition of this new
>   feature, you can learn by doing -- trying out a number of DynamoDB
>   features without even writing any code. You can create a table, add
>   some items, and see them in the table, all through a very clean and
>   simple user interface.

This is obviously a very convenient addition to the rich client options referenced in my initial answer above, please check out the post itself for a short illustrated *tour to help you get started*.

Comment: Thanks - would use the VS plugin, but turns out that AWS now has a DynamoDB database explorer built in to the console. Handy!

Comment: @ChrisWard: That's indeed very handy and I've added that information to a related answer yesterday accordingly, but refrained from doing so here due to the explicit request for a _Desktop Client_ - given it triggered you closing the case I might as well add it here too though, thanks :)

Comment: Neither toolkit seems to support editing List or Map values - a big problem if you are using dynamodb as a document store

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/workbench.settingup.html

Comment: @SteffenOpel You should update the answer to point this https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Using.Workbench.html

Answer (score 87):

If you are using DynamoDB local for development you can use the built-in DynamoDB shell: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Tools.DynamoDBLocal.Shell.html

http://localhost:8000/shell

UPDATE: Amazon does also provide an official client: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/workbench.html

Comment: It's unfortunate that it doesn't allow you to connect to a remote database.

Comment: And doesn't have a simple way to navigate through data but is script-based

Comment: Even more unfortunate, the page doesn't exist anymore.

Comment: For local DynamoDBs you can also use Dynobase - https://dynobase.dev/dynamodb-local-admin-gui/

Comment: Amazon now has an official client for accessing DynamoDB databases called [NoSQL Workbench](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/workbench.html), installable directly or via brew/Chocolatey/etc.

Comment: FWIW, sqlite clients got me the data access I needed.

Answer (score 12):

RazorSQL Database GUI Tool for Amazon DynamoDB

http://razorsql.com/articles/razorsql_amazon_dynamodb.html

Comment: too bad it costs $100 per license

Comment: and it's slow and error-prone

Comment: Also from what I could gather the importing doesn't work.

Comment: and if you want to delete everything you need to select it one by one. They don't provide select all feature which is very frustrating. I need to delete everything before testing my feature and I have to select each row one by one. 

I can write a script to delete everything but if you are providing a utility and charging for it. You must provide everything

Answer (score -10):

Amazon provides a local client for DynamoDb. It's a java jar and it runs on Linux and Windows.

It starts a server that binds to port 8000 at localhost (or you can specify another port when you start the server).

Download and unpack the desktop client, change the endpoint inside your app to localhost:8000, and then you can use the desktop client for DynamoDb.

[Here](http://aws.typepad.com/aws/2013/09/dynamodb-local-for-desktop-development.html) you can download and read about installing the dynamodb desktop client.

Comment: Unless the link has changed, that doesn't seem to be a desktop client; it is a local implementation of the DynamoDB protocol that doesn't allows you to write apps that use Dynamo without actually connecting to AWS (for development/testing purposes).